# How to get the document ID from firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a table view and when I swipe and delete the table view cell, I need the data in Firebase to delete as well. For that to be possible, I need to have the document ID. How can I get that so I can delete the table view cell and the data in Firebase?

This is the first `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase
import Firestore
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var db:Firestore!
    var employeeArray = [employee]()
    var employeeKey:String = ""
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        loadData()
        checkForUpdates()
        
        
    }
    
      
    
    func loadData() {
        db.collection("employee").getDocuments() {
            querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }else{
                self.employeeArray = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({employee(id: $0.documentID, xdictionary: $0.data())})
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func checkForUpdates() {
        db.collection("employee").whereField("timeStamp", isGreaterThan: Date())
            .addSnapshotListener {
                querySnapshot, error in
                guard let snapshots = querySnapshot else {return}
                
                snapshots.documentChanges.forEach {
                    diff in
                    
                    if diff.type == .added {
                        self.employeeArray = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({employee(id: $0.documentID, xdictionary: $0.data())})
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
   
    func UID()  {

        self.db.collection("employee").getDocuments() { (snapshot, err) in

           if let err = err {
               print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
           } else {
               for document in snapshot!.documents {

                 if document == document {
                     print(document.documentID)
                    }
                      }
           }
       }
    }
      
   
    
    @IBAction func addEmployee(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let composeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Employee", message: "Add Employee", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        composeAlert.addTextField { (textField:UITextField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Name"
        }
        
        composeAlert.addTextField { (textField:UITextField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Adress"
        }
        
        
        composeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        
        composeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add Employee", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
               
                if let name = composeAlert.textFields?.first?.text,
                let adress = composeAlert.textFields?.last?.text {
                let newEmployee = employee(name: name, adress: adress,timeStamp: Date())
                
                var ref:DocumentReference? = nil
                
                ref = self.db.collection("employee").addDocument(data: newEmployee.dictionary) {
                    error in
                    
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error adding document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }else{
                        print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }))
        
        self.present(composeAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return employeeArray.count
        
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        
        let tweet1 = employeeArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(tweet1.name) \(tweet1.adress)"
        cell .detailTextLabel?.text = "\(tweet1.timeStamp) "
        
        
        return cell
        
        
    }
    
   
    
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) async {
            print(UID())
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
  
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete) {
            
            db.collection("employee").document("\(UID())")
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is the second `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase
import Firestore
protocol DocumentSeriziable {
    init?(id: String, xdictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct employee {
    var name: String!
    var adress: String!
    var timeStamp: Date
   
    
        var dictionary:[String: Any] {
        return[
            "name":name!,
            "adress":adress!,
            "timeStamp":timeStamp,
          
            
        ]
    }
    
}

extension employee : DocumentSeriziable {
    
    init?(id: String, xdictionary dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
              let adress = dictionary["adress"] as? String,
              let timeStamp = dictionary["timeStamp"] as? Date else {return nil}
        self.init(name: name, adress: adress, timeStamp: timeStamp)
    }
}
```

I've tried to get the Document Id a couple of different ways but none of them worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in struct employee `var documentID: String`
And in `self.init(documentID: id, name: name, adress: adress, timeStamp: timeStamp)` and use

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete) {
        db.collection("cities").document(employeeArray[indexPath.row].documentID).delete() { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error removing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully removed!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add the self.documentID = id right after the init call, it gives me an error saying 'self' used before 'self. init' call or assignment to 'self'.  any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Replace for this self.init(documentID: id, name: name, adress: adress, timeStamp: timeStamp)

Comment: I'm getting an error because this code is not in a class I think, the code you just gave me didn't work and it just gave me another error. Is there another way to fix this error "'self' used before 'self. init' call or assignment to 'self'.

Comment: I tested code from my device. It works fine. Add in struct employee new var documentID: String and replace self.init for this self.init(documentID: id, name: name, adress: adress, timeStamp: timeStamp)

Comment: When I change the self.init with your code it gives me an error saying Incorrect argument labels in call (have 'documentID:name:adress:timeStamp:', expected 'name:adress:timeStamp:documentID:')

Comment: You need add var documentID: String in first position in struct empoyee) (Before name var)